# iframe. Элементы интерфейса

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Вопрос: как убрать эту кнопку-ссылку в левом нижнем углу фрейма?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все зависит от того, какой ресурс открывает ваш iframe.

Если ссылка на ресурс имеет такой же домен, что и сайт, на котором расположен ваш iframe вы можете легко обратиться к окну внутри iframe.
Например:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
iframe.document.getElementById("id").remove()
```

Если ссылка на ресурс внутри iframe имеет другой домен, то получение данных о её контенте или какое-либо изменение её содержимого *не является возможным из-за политики одинакового источника* ([подробнее тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)).

Однако, если у вас есть доступ к серверу, с которого вы берете контент в iframe, вы можете разрешить другому сайту брать с него информацию, добавив его в значение заголовка **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**. ([подробнее тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin))